# VBA - excluding wildcard values in autofilter?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to make 2 excel sheets. One for all accounts of a certain customer, one without. Unfortunately, the way the customer name is laid out, I have to search for these customers using a wildcard.

The Macro for only the customer works fine, but the macro to exclude the customer does not.

Working Macro:

```
Sheets("AR Aging").Range("A:J").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array( _
"*COMPANY*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

Range("A:J").Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(7)
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets(8).Select
Sheets(8).Name = "XYZ"

Sheets("AR Aging").AutoFilterMode = False
Sheets("AR Aging").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

The only difference is in the non-working macro,

```
Criteria1:=Array( "*COMPANY*")
```

was changed to

```
Criteria1:=Array( "<>*COMPANY*")
```

and the sheet numbers were changed.

Comment: remove the array() part

Comment: When asking a question, remember to include the exact content of error messages you encounter. In this case it was probably "AutoFilter method of Range class failed".